# How to have "current_user" (coded as `session[:user_id]`) show user email, instead of some weird code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms-authentication

I followed a tutorial on Rails forms (login,logout). All went well except for this bit: Once a user has logged in, the bottom of the page should say "You are logged in as" followed by an email address, so it will say, for example, "You are logged in as Jane@aol.com". The line of code responsbile for this:

`<p>You are logged in as: <%= @current_user %></p>`

However, what I get instead is `You are logged in as: #<User:000s500r00k000h0>` (Not an exact copy)

For the life of me, I cannot figure out what that number is and why the user's email doesn't show up-nor where to begin troubleshooting:

`current_user` is defined in ApplicationController:

`class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception`

`def authentication_required
    if !logged_in?
      redirect_to login_path
    end
  end`

`def logged_in?
    !!current_user
  end`

`def current_user
    @current_user ||= begin
      User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end
  end
  helper_method :current_user
end`

The `user_id` ought to be the user's email. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly some of your code seems wrong

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authentication_required

  def authentication_required
    redirect_to login_path if !logged_in?
  end

  def logged_in? 
    current_user.present?
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id] 
  end
  helper_method :current_user
end
```

You are creating a helper method so you don't need to call `@current_user`, just call `current_user`

Also, `session[:user_id]` is not the `email`. It's the ID. You are using it to find the user with `User.find(session[:user_id])`. This is the same as `User.find(1)` .

`#<User:000s500r00k000h0>` is a reference to the user object you've assigned to `@current_user`, the numbers are the space in memory where it's stored.

All you need to do is call the method that you would like to display for the signed in user. If `email` then `email` and if `username` then `username` etc

Comment: Thank you! The reason I am trying to figure out this `current_user` issue is: the tutorial was demonstrating secure login/logout and how to keep certain information private (or safe from hacking)-hence `current_user` instead of `user.email` (though honestly I haven't learned enough to understand it all). And the tutorial shows the logged-in user's email.

Comment: The email will only ever be displayed to a logged in user anyway as the before_action :authentication_required will redirect anyone that is not logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Just change `<p>You are logged in as: <%= @current_user %></p>` to `<p>You are logged in as: <%= @current_user.user_id %></p>`.  What you are currently seeing as `#<User:000s500r00k000h0>` is just a representation of a User object itself.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify what you want from the `@current_user` as such:

```
<p>You are logged in as: <%= @current_user.email %></p>
```

If you don't specify, Rails will just throw out *what* the `@current_user` is.